# Can I store the output data-set of a console app in the memory for the next execution?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, console-application

I have one console app that runs **almost every minute**.
It produces some data.

Fine until this point.

**My question is**:
If I want to execute a logic on the data "that was produced by the same console app in the previous execution"; how can I retrieve this previous data?

Please note that **I want to avoid round-trips to Db every minute** and I am thinking if there is a way to keep the console app. data in the memory somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If possible save DataTable as XML on you mahcine and than Read back this XML in DataTable when you want it. that will do work for you

[DataTable.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hyx9hb4.aspx)  - Writes the current contents of the DataTable as XML using the specified file.

[DataTable.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0z9zxd.aspx) - Reads XML schema and data into the DataTable from the specified file.

Comment: Why XML but not a plain text file? (Would it have an impact on the performance?)

Comment: @pencilCake - because it i think thee is already exitingh method than can write and read xml easily in datatable that y xml fil..

Comment: Plain text would do too; what format is the data in? Is it what your application writes to the console window?

Comment: It is a collection of entities (from my domain model)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to keep the data in memory as it is lost when the program completes it execution.

There are two options:

1. Write the data to a local file and then read that back the next time the program runs.
2. Modify the program so that it runs continuously and loops. In this case you *will* be able to keep the data in memory as the program hasn't terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data on HD. And preferred way will be use BinaryFormatter.
Example:

```
    public static Byte[] SerializeObject(Object obj)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.TypeFormat = FormatterTypeStyle.TypesWhenNeeded;
        formatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;

        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    public static Object DeserializeObject(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.TypeFormat = FormatterTypeStyle.TypesWhenNeeded;
        formatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;

        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
```

I dont test it but you can try to load/save it to [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile%28VS.100%29.aspx) (.NET 4.0)